# eliminate the extra space in the page footer

Tags: css

i am trying to remove the extra line in the page footer, i tried to edit my css but its useless , i have 4 css IDs on the page `content` , `search`, `button_style` and `ad` which is acting as my footer here , the porblem that i need remove the blue line below the page as you see in the screen shot , here is my code

```
#content {
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: 6px solid #BDF4FC ;
    width: 50%;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 15px;
    margin-top: 10%;
    background-color: #ffffff;

}

#search {
    height: 42px;
    border: medium solid #63D1F2;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-style: normal;
    color: #CCC;
    font-weight: bolder;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-left:7%;
    margin-top:7%;
    position:relative;
    text-indent:10px;


}

#button_style {
    background-image: url(images/search_button.png);
    height: 44px;
    width: 92px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: 0px none #FFF;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-top:7%;
    margin-left:1px;
}

#ad {
    width:auto;
    height:190px;
    background-color:#FFF;
    margin-top:5%;
    border-top-width: 10px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-top-color: #12ADDA;
    border-right-color: #EDEDED;
    border-bottom-color: #EDEDED;
    border-left-color: #EDEDED;
    padding-top:40px;
    float: none;

}

<body>
<div id="buttonsmenu">
HOME | LOGIN | REGISTER | ABOUT US | HELP
</div>


<div id="content">

<form action="" method="get">
<input name="search" type="text" id="search" onfocus="clearContents(this);" onchange="RestContents(this);" value="Search Reservation" size="40" /><input type="submit" value="" id="button_style"/>
</form>
</div>
<div id="ad"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

any suggestions ?

[image: how to remove the extra blue line]

Comment: hard to say without seeing the html source, but it looks like a border

Comment: @rfausak sorry , i've updated the code to include the html code, the blue stripped line is not a border.

Comment: can we see some bare-bones html markup?

Comment: where are the diagonal lines coming from? What element are they the background of? `<body>` ? You seemed to have left out that css

Comment: The only thing using color #12ADDA is `#ad { .. border-top-color: #12ADDA; .. }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just think that is padding in your `<body>` try this

CSS

```
    html, body {padding-bottom:0;}
```

do that and then if you were sizing you body tag or anything just make sure you don't give it any padding on the bottom.

Comment: keep in mind if this works you should consider using a CSS reset on your document

Comment: when i added that on my `body` css, the background start to look wrong , the strips is not organized in some point of the page, that happened when i add `html` to the css.